# Is it possible to use a return value from one object in one class and use it in another

Tags: python, class, object

How can i use the value returned by the object whichGender and use it in the object display. I saw a question similar on stack overflow but didn't really get the answer.

```
class intro: 
        def __init__(self, name, age, gender, race):
            self.name = name
            self.age = age
            self.gender = gender
            self.race = race
    
        def display(self):  #object display
            print(f"The main character's name is {self.name}, the main character's gender is {self.gender}, his/her ")#i want to have the word his or her 
    
    
class Gender:  
            def __init__(self, gender):
                self.gender = gender
        
            def whichGender(self):
                if self.gender == 'male':
                    **return 'his'**  
                elif self.gender == 'female':
                    **return 'her**'
```

Comment: intro has a property that's Gender type, then inside `display` do `pron = self.gender.wichGender() ` and use it... in genderclass wichgender put what you suggest without **

Comment: @UlisesBussi that is giving me an error

Comment: wich error? and please show how you're implementing this, it's hard to debug blindfold

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def whichGender(gender):
    if gender == 'male':
        return 'his'
    elif gender == 'female':
        return 'her'

class intro: 
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender, race):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
        self.race = race

    def display(self):  #object display
        print(f"The main character's name is {self.name}, the main character's gender is {self.gender}, {whichGender(self.gender)}")


intro("et", 3, "female", "ET").display()
```